# Трепанация пустых параметров URL адресной строки передаваемых методом GET через регулярные выражения на PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, url, get, парсер

Не могу отучить от жадности.

```
$url_param="?type=search&keyword=test&c20=&c17=&pstat=1&start_date=&end_date=&doctype[]=15"
```

Нужно получить на выходе

```
$url_param="?type=search&keyword=test&pstat=1&doctype[]=15"
```

пытаюсь решить задачу так:

```
$url_param=preg_replace('/&.+?=&/i','&',$url_param);
```

но результат выходит зачастую так:

```
?type=search&c1=&end_date=&doctype[]=15
```

Даже уже сообразил так:

```
/&+?[a-z0-9_-]+=&/
```

но он находит только '&c20=&' и '&start_date=&'
затрагивая последний символ
что исключает потом &c17= и &end_date=.

Есть решения?

Comment: не используйте регулярные выражения - вам нужно просто распарсить строку (`parse_str()`), выкинуть лишнее, затем собрать обратно (`http_build_query()`).

Comment: @Etki почему бы это не оформить ответом?

Comment: @tutankhamun never enough time

Comment: Etki, спасибо за совет. Visman привел хороший пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обработка массива параметров через фильтр с рекурсией:

```
$url_param = "?type=search&keyword=test&c20=&c17=&pstat=1&start_date=&end_date=&doctype[]=15&doctype[]=";

parse_str($url_param, $output);

function af(&$value)
{
    if (is_array($value))
    {
        $value = array_filter($value, 'af');
        return count($value) != 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return $value !== '';
    }
}

$output = array_filter($output, 'af');

echo "<pre>\n";
var_dump(urldecode(http_build_query($output)));
echo "</pre>\n";
```

Comment: Скрипт возвращает в начале непонятную строку
string(242) 
"type=search...

Comment: @Intacto Так это же результат функции `var_dump`

Comment: Ну и нафиг он мне? ну ладно, уберу сам.
Хотя я уже решил задачу с помощью регулярки как оно и требовалось по заголовку топика, я протестировал скрипт Ваш снова и получил не то:
исходная строка: 
status=search&keyword=test&cat=file&c2=&c1=&pstat=0&start_date=&end_date=&doctypemain=1&doctype[]=15&doctype[]=13

полученная:
status=search&keyword=test&cat=file&pstat=0&doctypemain=1&doctype[0]=15&doctype[1]=13
 
Видите разницу в значениях doctype?

Comment: Несмотря на то что в полученный результат добавляются ключи для массива doctype, ваше решение - первый рабочий вариант. И оно работает без регулярных выражений, что придает красивости коду. Спасибо за это решение, сам я забыл про такие встроенные функции в PHP. Приятно вспомнить.  Тем не менее для каких то специфичных задач, кому надо, придется работать с регулярными выражениями по старинке.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответы. Заинтересовала данная задача, решение ниже.

```
$url_param="type=search&keyword=test&c20=&c17=&pstat=1&start_date=&end_date=&doctype[]=15";

parse_str($url_param, $e);

foreach($e as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value)) continue;
    $output[$key] = $value;
}

echo http_build_query($output);
```

Comment: Других нет, кроме вашего. Решение неполно.

Comment: @Visman Уверены, что не будут? Так дополните.

Comment: Проверьте ваш код хотя бы на таком примере `type=search&keyword=test&c20=&c17=&pstat=1&start_date=&end_date=&doctype[]=` P.S. Первое мое предложение не относится к будущему времени.

Comment: @Visman я вроде как дополнить просил

Comment: да пожалуйста. Смотрите мой ответ.

Comment: Мне очень нравится компактность кода и его логичность. При проверке значения &doctype[]= заменились на &doctype%5B0%5D
а &pstat=0 вооще ушло из параметров URL так как 0 принимается за пустоту.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы.
Сам решил почти таким же образом.
(Хотя хотелка еще долго хотела решить все красиво одной строчкой)

Версия 0.3 (убран параметр break)

```
    function convert($url,$_f=0){
        $_all = '/(&+?[a-z0-9_-]+=)&{1}/i';
        $_end = '/(&+?[a-z0-9_-]+)=$/i';
        return preg_replace(($_f)?$_end:$_all,($_f)?'':'&',$url,1);
    }

    $url_result = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $url_param = ''; 
    while ($url_param != $url_result){
        $url_param = $url_result;
        $url_result = convert($url_param);
    }   $url_result = convert($url_param,1); 

    echo $url_result;
```

Версия 0.2 (исправленная, красивая, дополненная)

```
    function convert($url_param,$flag=0){
        $rule_all = '/(&+?[a-z0-9_-]+=)&{1}/i';
        $rule_end = '/(&+?[a-z0-9_-]+)=$/i';
        return preg_replace(($flag)?$rule_end:$rule_all,($flag)?'':'&',$url_param,1);
    }

    $url_result = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); $url_param = ""; 
    $iwhile=0; while ($url_param != $url_result){ $iwhile++; if ($iwhile>200) break;
        $url_param=$url_result;
        $url_result=convert($url_param);
    }   $url_result = convert($url_param,1); 

    echo $url_result;
```

Версия 0.1 (тоже рабочая, но старая)

```
        $url_param=urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); // Получаем параметры URL
        $url_result=preg_replace('/(&+?[a-z0-9_-]+=)&{1}/i','&',$url_param,1); //Делаем замену по первому вхождению только

        /*  Запускаем цикл до тех пор пока есть что вырезать или пока не сработает счетчик безопасности.*/ $iwhile=0; // счетчик
        while ($url_param != $url_result){$iwhile++;

            $url_param=$url_result; // Сохраняем свежий результат
            $url_result=preg_replace('/(&+?[a-z0-9_-]+=)&{1}/i','&',$url_param,1); // делаем опять вырезание до первого вхождения и отправляем обратно в цикл на проверку
            if ($iwhile>200) break; // проверяем счетчик безопасности

        }
        $url_result=preg_replace('/(&+?[a-z0-9_-]+)=$/i','',$url_result,1); // напоследок проверяем последнее значение, в котором может не быть знака & в конце
```

В результате получаем наше $url_result

Comment: Слишком уж костыльно и неочевидно.

Comment: ну для тех кто не силен в регулярке - может и костыльно, но работает стабильно... и нету пока нареканий

Comment: Проблема не в сложности регулярок. У вас одна и та же строка кода (с дублирующейся регуляркой) используется дважды. А если придется править код, где гарантия, что вы оба куска измените? А еще одна _почти такая_ же регулярка используется в последней строчке... Это и называется "костыльно"

Comment: Ах это - ну это первая версия, конечно же повторяющиеся куски уберутся в функцию ))

Comment: Добавил функцию, убрал повторения